# What glasses can Dogmeat wear?

Tags: fallout-4

I've only been playing Fallout 4 for a couple of weeks when I can. I've got **DOGMEAT** wearing the **Red Bandana**.

Which glasses can he wear? I've tried several different types but haven't found any he would wear. I've seen a picture of him that look like he's wearing RayBan Wayfarers (though I can't find it right now).

I've tried Sunglasses, Patrolman Sunglasses, Glasses, welding goggles, and a couple of others but he can't wear them.

Which types can he wear and is there a place that I can find some (either a vendor or location)?

Comment: I think you have a typo in your third paragraph.  I'm not sure of that, though, so I left it alone.  Otherwise, I edited your title, and removed the picture; it wasn't needed.

Comment: The picture that @Frank removed looks like [black-rim glasses](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Black-rim_glasses).

Comment: Could you find and link to the picture you saw of Dogmeat in the sunglasses? It would help in finding which in-game item it is.

Comment: I liked that original title just fine.

Comment: @DCShannon - I liked my original title better too.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to the [Dogmeat page on Nukapedia](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Dogmeat_%28Fallout_4%29#Equipment), the only glasses Dogmeat can wear are Welding Goggles. That page also lists all the other pieces of apparel Dogmeat can equip.

The glasses you included in your initial picture look like [Black-Rim Glasses](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Black-rim_glasses), and also like [Liam's Glasses](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Liam's_glasses). You could try these yourself if you'd like to check.

Comment: Aww :/ Maybe I'd actually use Dogmeat if he could rock some aviators...

Comment: I thought the picture I originally saw had black sunglasses like Ray Bans. I found it when trying to figure out how to make Dogmeat wear the bandanna. I can't find it now of course.

Comment: I did find another pair of **Welding Googles** and got Dogmeat to wear them.

Answer (score 3):

I know he can wear welding goggles, he has them on two of my characters. I think wrapparound goggles work as well but I may be misremembering, on mobile and can't test.

Answer (score 1):

> I've tried Sunglasses, Patrolman Sunglasses, Glasses, welding goggles, and a couple of others but he can't wear them.

He can definitely wear welding goggles, so you must be doing something wrong.

You need to trade with Dogmeat, put the goggles in his inventory, and then Equip them (triangle on PS4, don't know about other platforms).

Welding goggles are one of the easiest eyewear to find, you can often scavenge them from Raiders you kill.